# Find ResultSet column count?

Tags: java, resultset

How do I find out how many values are in a single ResultSet.

I know you use result.next() to iterate between results, but how can I tell how many values are indexed in one result? So for the example:

```
while (resultSet.next()) {
        resultSet.getString(1);
        resultSet.getString(2);
        resultSet.getString(3);
```

}

How can I tell if there is a value at resultSet.getString(4); before executing it?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are trying to get the column count returned.

```
 int colCount= resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
```

That gives the count of returned column count.

Comment: exactly what I wanted, thank you very much